# Accessing Media files in Google Storage from Dialogflow fullfillment

Tags: google-cloud-storage, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

How can we access media files stored on cloud storage from dialogflow ?

I am able to access the files if I make them public but what are the other options ?
Is it supposed to work if we grant access to the  service  (dialogflow and/or firebase ) accounts ?

```
 // https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses
 // Create a media response

 conv.ask(new MediaObject({
   name: track.title,
   url: track.source,
   description: track.artist,
   icon: new Image({
     url: track.image,
     alt: 'Media icon'
   })
 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

No, granting access to the service accounts that you're running your Action under are insufficient. Your Action runs in the cloud, but the audio file is downloaded directly by the user's device.

One technique that should work is to use a [Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). This lets you put access restrictions on the cloud storage bucket, but generate a URL to access the file for a limited time.

Comment: Thx for the reply ! I believe the user would have access to the file anyways if it’s getting downloaded so a signed url might not help in this case . I understand on the google home they cannot access but maybe on a pixel book they can. The goal was to try and secure the media file . How does it work with Spotify and YouTube music and so on ? In their case also does it download the media ? guessing they secure in some fashion so the files cannot be used outside of the app